# google map with current Location

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello I tried to add a google map with current Location using [this code](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/06/using-google-maps-api-v2-to-get-current.html) but I got an error with method getMap (cannot resolve method) Can you help me?
What's this method? How can I add it?

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment{
    private TextView locationText;
    private TextView addressText;
    private GoogleMap map;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        locationText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        addressText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        replaceMapFragment();
        return rootView;
    }
    private void replaceMapFragment() {
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener());
    }
    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener() {
        return new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Marker marker;
                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
                locationText.setText("You are at [" + longitude + " ; " + latitude + " ]");
                new GetAddressTask(MapFragment.this).execute(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        };
    }
    public void callBackDataFromAsyncTask(String address) {
        addressText.setText(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `fragment_map.xml`?

Comment: As per @Ironman's answer, why are you using a deprecated method?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using fragment i suggest you to try this way

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

JavaCode

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

For more see [this](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551)

Comment: thanks but this code doesn't show my current location. It shows a static location CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);